# Google Analytics API how to retrieve next page of data

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-client

I'm using the Google Analytics API to retrieve reporting data for one of my profiles. If the number of rows in the report exceeds 1000, the response contains 1,000 results plus a parameter called `nextPage`, which contains a URL for the next page of data.  I am confused how to actually use this URL in order to retrieve the data. What API method to I use to actually get the next page of data.  Here's my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Analytics'); // name of your app

// set assertion credentials
$client->setAssertionCredentials(
  new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(

    GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_SERVICE_EMAIL, // email you added to GA

    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),

    file_get_contents(storage_path().'/keys/privatekey.p12')  // keyfile you downloaded

));

$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_CLIENT_ID);           // from API console

$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

$result = $service->data_ga->get(
        'ga:'.DEFAULT_VIEW_ID,
        '2014-09-01',
        '2015-01-26',
        'ga:uniquePageViews',
        array(
                'dimensions'=>'ga:dimension1',
                'filters'=>'ga:dimension3==product'
        )
);

print_r($result);
```

The result of this is `Google_Service_Analytics_GaData` object, which contains data for 1000 rows plus this:

```
[nextLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:86454007&dimensions=ga:dimension1&metrics=ga:uniquePageViews&filters=ga:dimension3%3D%3Dproduct&start-date=2014-09-01&end-date=2015-01-26&start-index=1001&max-results=1000
```

How can I use this `nextLink` to retrieve the next page of data? There must be some mechanism for this built into the Google SDK, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the parameters in that link you'll notice it's the same as your original query, but the `start-index` value is set to `1001`:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?
  ids=ga:86454007&
  dimensions=ga:dimension1&
  metrics=ga:uniquePageViews&
  filters=ga:dimension3%3D%3Dproduct&
  start-date=2014-09-01&
  end-date=2015-01-26&
  start-index=1001&
  max-results=1000
```

So basically you have to keep doing queries until `start-index` + `itemsPerPage` > `totalResults`. Also, if you know you're going to have a large dataset, you can often set the `max-results` field to something higher like `10000`.

It's not part of the PHP SDK, but [this module](https://github.com/googleanalytics/javascript-api-utils/blob/master/lib/account-summaries/index.js#L59-L64) shows an example of making multiple requests until `totalResults` is reached.